# Unable to embed styling in aspose ppt which is rendered from html file

Tags: java, html, css, aspose, pptp

I am converting html to ppt using aspose java library. But, I couldn't generate styles like (padding,background-color,etc) whereas styles like(color,font-size) are working just fine,have a look at the code..

```
 public class poi {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            // The path to the documents directory.
            String dataDir = Utils.getDataDir(poi.class);

            // Create Empty presentation instance
            Presentation pres = new Presentation();

            // Access the default first slide of presentation
            ISlide slide = pres.getSlides().get_Item(0);

            // Adding the AutoShape to accommodate the HTML content
            IAutoShape ashape = slide.getShapes().addAutoShape(ShapeType.Rectangle,  50, 150, 300, 150);

            ashape.getFillFormat().setFillType(FillType.NoFill);

            // Adding text frame to the shape
            ashape.addTextFrame("");

            // Clearing all paragraphs in added text frame
            ashape.getTextFrame().getParagraphs().clear();

            // Loading the HTML file using InputStream
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dataDir + "file.html");
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();
            String content = ReadFile(dataDir + "file.html");

            // Adding text from HTML stream reader in text frame
            ashape.getTextFrame().getParagraphs().addFromHtml(content);

            // Saving Presentation
            pres.save(dataDir + "output.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);


        }

        public static String ReadFile(String FileName) throws Exception {

            File file = new File(FileName);
            StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String text = null;

                // repeat until all lines is read
                while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    contents.append(text).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return contents.toString();

        }

    }
```

As you can see I am loading the html file which has inline styling, but I couldn't quite make most of the css elements to load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

@Balchandar Reddy,

I have observed your requirements and like to share that at present Aspose.Slides support basic text import along with limited tag support in presentations generated using Aspose.Slides. I request you to please share the required HTML with desired tags for which you intend to have support in Aspose.Slides. I will discuss that with our product team and will add that as new feature request in our issue tracking system.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: My requirement is quite complex, it includes html tables with each cell having different background-color and some pages have various charts like bar,column and pie,etc..is this possible to do with aspose?

Comment: @Balchandar Reddy at present, Aspose.Slides only support basic text import from HTML to presentation text frames.